# How to do differentiaton and intergration in python 3

Tags: python-3.x

Does anyone know how to do differentiation and intergration in python 3.5 if so please say so I know there is a module called sympy but don't know how to use it. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what kind of integration you are trying to do. If you mean symbolic integration (i.e. integrate(x, dx) --> (1/2)*x^2) then you need sympy. It is easy to use and there is extensive and [excellent documentation available](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/index.html).

If you mean numerical integration you should install **Numpy** and **Scipy**. There is a `numpy.trapz` function and a `scipy.integrate` function that should help you in this case. For differentiation there is a `numpy.diff` function that should work. Note that for numerical integration there are different methods that yield different results and you must pick the best depending on the type of problem you are trying to solve and what kind of accuracy you are trying to get.